# Authenticating cross-origin REST requests in IE < 10 not possible?

Tags: rest, oauth, single-sign-on, single-page-application

Per this [MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx) Internet Explorer 8 and 9 do not support the ability to set header parameters on Cross Site requests, which means that [CORS support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors) is amazingly limited.

Put simply (if I understand correctly), in IE 8 or IE 9 it is not possible to set an authorization header (OAuth token) on a AJAX request to a REST service running on another origin from the user-agent's current location.

Is that correct, or am I missing something obvious?  Doesn't this effectively kill the ability to deliver a single page application (ie: AngularJS) which needs authenticated access to REST resources?  Is there a fallback pattern that I'm not seeing at the moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, IE 8 and 9 are limited as indicated in the links provided.

Answering my own question... We've chosen to circumvent this by adding a routing rule in our load balancer to accept requests on the expected origin domain, plus a special infix path, and to rewrite the request URL to our preffered URL.

In other words, the Single Page Application (SPA), when running in IE < 10, will make an ajax request to https://theApplication.com/IEsux/foo/v1/... and the load balancer will rewrite this within our network to https://api.ourDomain.com/foo/v1/...

This will work for the cases where we host the SPA and thus calls to /IEsux will traverse our load balancer.  Unfortunately, as soon as we have an external vendor that creates their own SPA and wants to use our REST API, this will fail.

Alternatives welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

You can do [jsonp requests](http://jaketrent.com/post/make-jsonp-requests-with-angularjs/) with angular:

But it's very limited